# scrapy nothing save in csv file. What's wrong?

Tags: scrapy

I try to run this code and save it as csv file but in csv contain nothing. Is there any wrong in the code? Please help. Thanks in advance

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from amazon.items import AmazonItem

class AmazonSpider(Spider):
name = "amazon"
allowed_domains = ["amazon.com"]
start_urls = [

"http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=9780316324106",
"http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=9780307959478",
"http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=9780345549334"

]

def parse(self, response):
   sel = Selector(response)
   sites = sel.xpath('//div[@class="fstRow prod celwidget"]')
   items = []
   for site in sites:
       item = AmazonItem()
       item['url'] = response.url
       item['price'] = site.xpath('//ul[@class="rsltL"]/li[5]/a/span/text()')
       if item['price']:
          item['price'] = item['price'].extract()[0]
       else:
          item['price'] = "NA"
          items.append(item)
   return items
```

I would like to save if item not found then replace with the "NA" character.

When I try this code below it's work fine:

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from amazon.items import AmazonItem

class AmazonSpider(Spider):
name = "amazon"
allowed_domains = ["amazon.com"]
start_urls = [

"http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=9780316324106",
"http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=9780307959478",
"http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=9780345549334"

]

def parse(self, response):
   sel = Selector(response)
   sites = sel.xpath('//div[@class="fstRow prod celwidget"]')
   items = []
   for site in sites:
       item = AmazonItem()
       item['url'] = response.url
       item['price'] = site.xpath('//ul[@class="rsltL"]/li[5]/a/span/text()')
          items.append(item)
   return items
```

What's wrong in this part? or do I forget something?

```
       if item['price']:
      item['price'] = item['price'].extract()[0]
   else:
      item['price'] = "NA"
```

I am new in this. Would you helping me please. Thank you very much

Comment: Is this how your indentation is set in the original script?

Comment: How are you running the spider?

Comment: You need to clarify the difference in results between the two sets of code. Both sets return three results. What is the expected number of items to be returned?

Comment: And what should those items look like?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `items.append (item)` is indented too far in your first code sample.

This would make it part of the `else` block of your price check and so no items will get added to the `items` list unless it had no price set.

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from amazon.items import AmazonItem

class AmazonSpider(Spider):
    name = "amazon"
    allowed_domains = ["amazon.com"]
    start_urls = [

    "http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=9780316324106",
    "http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=9780307959478",
    "http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=9780345549334"

    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        sites = sel.xpath('//div[@class="fstRow prod celwidget"]')
        items = []
        for site in sites:
            item = AmazonItem()
            item['url'] = response.url
            item['price'] = site.xpath('//ul[@class="rsltL"]/li[5]/a/span/text()')
            if item['price']:
                item['price'] = item['price'].extract()[0]
            else:
                item['price'] = "NA"
            items.append(item)
        return items
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your suggestion. Do you have the example code to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `items` list, just use  `yield` statement

```
def parse(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)

    for site in sel.xpath('//div[@class="fstRow prod celwidget"]'):
        item = AmazonItem()
        item['url'] = response.url
        price = site.xpath('//ul[@class="rsltL"]/li[5]/a/span/text()')
        if price:
            item['price'] = price.extract()[0]
        else:
            item['price'] = "NA"

        yield item
```

Save to data.csv file:

```
scrapy crawl amazon -o data.csv -t csv
```